# Tomato OpenVPN Client forwarding setup

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, openvpn, tomato

I am using a VPN solely to get a dedicated/static IP (because my home network has a dynamic IP because its cable). I dont care about hiding my identity etc. I have the VPN set up on my router running Tomato firmware, using the OpenVPN Client.

What I want is when traffic comes into the VPNs IP, and hits my router, depending on the IP the traffic came from, it gets redirected to a specific device in my home network. Each device in my network has a static IP assigned, and in the past I used a different VPN that used PPTP, and that just worked, eg Tomato's normal Port Forwarding rules worked perfectly and depending on where the traffic came from, it was automatically routed to the right device connected to my router.

However now that I am using a VPN that uses OpenVPN instead of PPTP, it appears the Port Forwarding rules in Tomato no longer work? I cant work out how to send traffic to the correct device in my home network based on the port number and which IP sent the request. I noticed the "Routing Policy" tab in the OpenVPN Client setup page in Tomato, but that makes no sense to me.

Do I need to add some kind of script somewhere in Tomato? Some iptables rules or something? It seems weird I cant just use the Port Forwarding config page in Tomato. Or do I just need to enable/disable some of the options in the OpenVPN Client config page? Im out of my depth, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: I think what you should be looking into is dynamic DNS if you have a WAN address that's assigned by DHCP. Nginx for the reverse proxy, or something similar, I believe Appache also has reverse proxy functions.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - I dont think so. I need a static IP, specifically, not a domain name. Also the question is still valid regardless, I want to know how to configure port forwarding on Tomato when running the OpenVPN client

Comment: Just trying to point you in the right direction... Do you have an aversion to using a DNS name? It pretty much solves the first part of your problem. I understand what you are trying to do, just no idea why you would try to do it this way, it's abnormal.

Comment: I dont have an aversion, I am using this setup to run crypto masternodes on local devices, these specifically require static IP addresses, and do not work with DNS names.

Comment: @MatthewPrasinov: Have you looked at this existing question?

https://superuser.com/questions/718072/port-forwarding-on-a-tomato-router-with-openvpn-client-enabled

Answer (score 0):

I think my [question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TomatoFTW/comments/ebg09m/port_forwarding_to_a_device_behind_an_openvpn/fbd2rtt/) might help you.

I will duplicate it here:

> So, after looking with the [association providing the VPN](https://www.illyse.net/), we ended up with the following solution.
>
> - `192.168.1.1` is the default IP of the router, which can be changed in http://192.168.1.1/basic-network.asp.
> - `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` is the IP of the VPN tunnel.
>
> ---
>
> 1. To store a custom script that will run when the VPN is up (started), enable JFFS with the browser at http://192.168.1.1/admin-jffs2.asp. Save the settings and some services will be restarted (/jffs/ will be mounted).
> 2. Telnet in your router:
>
>    ```sh
>    telnet 192.168.1.1
>    ```
> 3. Login with `root` and the password you usually use to access Tomato.
> 4. Create and edit a script in /jffs/:
>
>    ```sh
>    vi /jffs/vpnup.sh
>    ```
> 5. Add the following to the script:
>
>    ```sh
>    #!/bin/sh
>
>    # Script to be run when the VPN is brought up
>
>    # Use the VPN to route all packets through the tunnel.
>    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY -j WANPREROUTING
>
>    # Apply the port forwarding rules to the tunnel.
>    iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun11 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -m state --state NEW -j wanin
>    ```
> 6. Save and quit vi by typing `Esc`, `:`, `w`, `q`, then `Enter`.
> 7. Make the script readable and executable by root only:
>
>    ```sh
>    chmod 700 /jffs/vpnup.sh
>    ```
> 8. Exit the telnet session:
>
>    ```sh
>    exit
>    ```
> 9. Add the following line to the “Custom Configuration” form control at http://192.168.1.1/vpn-client.asp, in the “Advanced” tab:
>
>    ```sh
>    up /jffs/vpnup.sh
>    ```
> 10. Save the settings.
> 11. (Re)start your VPN.
>
> Each time the VPN will be started, the iptables should now be updated to route all traffic through the VPN, and apply the port forwarding rules to its tunnel.
>
> Some useful commands to debug:
>
> - `ip addr show` (on the *Router*)
> - `ip route show` (on the *Router*)
> - `iptables -nvL` (on the *Router*)
> - `iptables -t nat -nvL` (on the *Router*)
> - `tcpdump -ni any port 80` (on the *Server*)

I hope that helps or will help.